# Java microservices project not showing Coverage As option on right clicking of project in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, microservices, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to cover the test cases coverage for my Java micro services project in STS, but when I right click on project, it is not showing me **Coverage As** option.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: And which test coverage plugin did you install into STS?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Idea:

Try to click the right button on any package and choose `More Run/Debug and then Run Test With Coverage`.
When you use the Gradle try to use the snippet above but do click on the package in test directory.